# How to change reply format of email?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When my boss responds to my email it sends the rest of our conversation as a separate attachment. This only occurs with my bosses email replies...I've been with him when he replies to others and he doesn't click anything to change the format, he just "replies" and sends. I believe it has something to do with his settings. Please help! I can't figure it out and it makes reading through email conversations difficult.

See photo below:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTJvQ.png)

Comment: No, because when I pointed it out to him yesterday, he had no idea it was doing that or how. He's in his 60's and barely knows how to use the computer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting to cause this to happen.

In Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013:

- File -> Options -> Mail -> *"Replies and forwards"* section.
- For *"When replying to a message"* change it to "Include original message text" (It's probably currently set to "Attach original message").

[image: Outlook Reply Text Options]

Answer (score 0):

From the latest version of Outlook:
Go to Options -> Mail -> Replies and Forwards. Select "Include original message text" to quote the conversation in the email body, or "Attach original message" if you prefer the entire conversation be included as an attachment.